# Where can I buy English translated Clockwork Planet light novels?

Tags: resources, clockwork-planet

Where can I find English translated Clockwork Planet light novels? Are there online shops which sell translated copies?

Comment: I don't think it is available legally. There is no English Wikipedia article, and Japanese article doesn't show any English publisher (if you are OK with Chinese, then there is a publisher) http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AD%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AF%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AF%E3%83%BB%E3%83%97%E3%83%A9%E3%83%8D%E3%83%83%E3%83%88

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Clockwork Planet* (『クロックワーク・プラネット』) light novels have not been licensed for English translation and distribution so far.

Yen Press has licensed *No Game No Life*, another light novel series by the same author, Kamiya Yuu; volume 1 was released in April 2015 and volume 2 will be released in July 2015. The highest chance of *Clockwork Planet* light novels being translated is currently through Yen Press, but Yen Press [has not](http://www.yenpress.com/2014/09/we-have-a-few-announcements-to-make/) licensed the series [so far](http://www.yenpress.com/2015/01/new-licenses-for-the-new-year/). You can make a request to express your interest by sending a message through their [contact form](https://www.hachettebookgroup.biz/contact-us/) or by posting a comment in response to their new licenses [announcement](http://www.yenpress.com/2015/01/new-licenses-for-the-new-year/).